# SSIS: Error Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, ssis

I hope you are well..
I really need your help to help me resolve an issue.

I created an SSIS package (SSIS 2012) which processes a tabular model in Azure AS.
To do this I created a task script (C # 2010) and I had to add 2 references Microsoft.AnalysisService.Core and Microsoft.AnalysisService.Tabular.
The package runs fine when I run it locally.

However when I deploy it on the SSIS server and run it I get this error: "Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.".

Do you know where this error could come from?
How can I resolve this error?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check DLL availability on the SSIS Server. Usually such message means that SSIS cannot start script task code by some reason.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your help. 
You are right. The dlls had not been installed on the SSIS server. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check DLL availability on the SSIS Server. Usually such message means that SSIS cannot start script task code by some reason